# Tranzila payment gateway : Not Authorized error message in response

Tags: php, php-curl

Trying to integrate tranzila payment gateway in my php project and testing with dummy credit card numbers on localhost before go live.I get php code from tranzila official document.
code given below

`

```
$tranzila_api_host  =  'secure5.tranzila.com'; 
$tranzila_api_path  =  '/cgi-bin/tranzila71u.cgi';

// Prepare transaction parameters 
$query_parameters['supplier'] = 'TERMINAL_NAME'; // 'TERMINAL_NAME' should be replaced by actual terminal name 
$query_parameters['sum']  =  '45';  // Transaction sum 
$query_parameters['currency'] = '1';  // Type of currency 1 NIS, 2 USD, 978 EUR, 826 GBP, 392 JPY 
$query_parameters['ccno']  = '12312312';  // Test card number 
$query_parameters['expdate']= '0820';  // Card expiry date: mmyy 
$query_parameters['myid']  = '12312312';  // ID number if required 
$query_parameters['mycvv']  = '123';  // number if required 
$query_parameters['cred_type'] = '1';  // This field specifies the type of transaction, 1 - normal transaction, 6 - credit, 8 - payments 
// $query_parameters['TranzilaPW'] = 'TranzilaPW' ; 

$query_string = '' ; 
foreach($query_parameters as $name => $value) { 
    $query_string .= $name.'='.$value.'&' ; 
}

$query_string  =  substr($query_string ,  0 ,  - 1 ) ;  // Remove trailing '&'

// Initiate CURL 
$cr = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cr,CURLOPT_URL ,"https://$tranzila_api_host$tranzila_api_path"); 
curl_setopt($cr,CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($cr,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true); 
curl_setopt($cr,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$query_string) ; 
curl_setopt($cr,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
curl_setopt($cr,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

// Execute request 
$result = curl_exec($cr); 
$error = curl_error($cr);

if(!empty($error)){ 
    die( $error ); 
} 
curl_close ($cr);

// Preparing associative array with response data 
$response_array = explode('&',$result); 
$response_assoc = array(); 
if(count($response_array) > 1){ 
    foreach($response_array as $value){ 
        $tmp = explode('=',$value); 
        if  (count($tmp) > 1 ){ 
            $response_assoc [$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1]; 
        } 
    } 
}

// Analyze the result string 
if(!isset($response_assoc['Response'])){ 
    die($result."\n"); 
    /**
     * When there is no 'Response' parameter it either means
     * that some pre-transaction error happened (like authentication
     * problems), in which case the result string will be in HTML format,
     * explaining the error, or the request was made for generate token only
     * (in this case the response string will only contain 'TranzilaTK'
     * parameter)
     */
}else if($response_assoc['Response'] !== '000'){ 
    die($response_assoc['Response']."\n"); 
    // Any other than '000' code means transaction failure 
    // (bad card, expiry, etc ..) 
}else{ 
    die("Success \n"); 
}
```

`

Here i replaced supplier with my original supplier name which i can't show here for security reasons.When run this code with actual supplier i got 'Not Authorized' error.

[image]

Comment: Did you actually leave the `TranzilaPW` parameter commented out?

Comment: Yes ! It is optional.If you set it in merchant panel then only you required to give in request.Since i didn't set so i am not sending it.but i tried with it also but not work.

Comment: Well it seems to expect some sort of authentication, which you are not currently providing … so what does the documentation say about that?

Comment: Is this the output you get from `die( $error )`? Then look at what the actual cURL response contains in that case as well, maybe there’s a more descriptive error message in there.

Comment: $error is empty.result is coming in $result.